# How do I make my Discord ban function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my Discord bot able to ban people, but the function is not working:

The relevant code is as follows:

```
banned_member = get(bot.get_all_members(), id=int_offender_id)

banned_member.ban(reason="Test")
```

It can find the banned_member object, but it cannot issue a ban. In the server, I created a role that allows the bot to ban people.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `.get_all_members()` is a [generator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_all_members#discord.Client.get_all_members) the get() isnt working.
And you want to filter by the id and it will return a list but it is only possible to have 1 id because its a set so take the only element out.
But if your search id isnt tested to be on the server take the second approach.
1.

```
banned_member = list(filter(bot.get_all_members(), int_offender_id))[0]
banned_member.ban(reason="Test")
```

2.

```
banned_member=bot.guilds[bot.guilds.index(server_id)].get_member(int_offender_id)
banned_member.ban(reason="Test")
```

Comment: The first solution yields the error "int" object is not iterable

For the second solution, could you elaborate on where you got the server_id?

Comment: server_id is the guild id.
1) If you use this bot only on your server search the id on discord and implemented it 
2) if you use this on more servers from the message ctx.guild_id